# Page scroll bar goes down when I resize the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create my own "sticky" behavior on a navigation bar and for a menu on the top, with only "position" and "float" properties and JavaScript. I did this exercice myself in order to improve my skills in JavaScript.

It's all working, the only problem I have is when I resize my page when positions are not static anymore. To reproduce the bug you must "run the code snippet" then click on "full page". Then, you have to scroll down in order to have the positions of "menu" and "sidebar" to be "fixed". Now, when you resize the page, you'll see the page scrolls down automatically.

```js
(function(){

    function makeSticky(element){
        var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();                                     
        var top = rect.top + scrollY;         

        var fakeElement = document.createElement('div'); 
        fakeElement.style.width = rect.width + "px";                      
        fakeElement.style.height = rect.height + "px"; 

        var offset = parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-offset') || 0, 10);   

        var hasDataConstraint = element.getAttribute('data-constraint');
        if(hasDataConstraint != null) {var constraint = document.querySelector(hasDataConstraint);}
        else {var constraint = document.body;}
        
        var constraintRect = constraint.getBoundingClientRect();
        var constraintBottom = constraintRect.top + scrollY + constraintRect.height - offset - rect.height;                 
        


        function onResize(){                                     
            element.style.width = "auto";      
            element.style.position = 'static';               
            fakeElement.style.display = "none";       
            rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            top = rect.top + scrollY; 

            fakeElement.style.width = rect.width + "px";
            fakeElement.style.height = rect.height + "px";
            fakeElement.style.display = "block";

            constraintRect = constraint.getBoundingClientRect();
            constraintBottom = constraintRect.top + scrollY + constraintRect.height - offset - rect.height; 

            onScroll();
        }
        


        function onScroll(){
            if(scrollY > constraintBottom && element.style.position != 'absolute'){
                element.style.position = "absolute";
                element.style.bottom = "0";
                element.style.top = "auto";
            }
            if(scrollY > top - offset && scrollY < constraintBottom && element.style.position != 'fixed') {  
                element.style.position = 'fixed';
                element.style.top = offset + 'px';
                element.style.bottom = 'auto';
                element.style.width = rect.width + "px";  

                element.parentElement.insertBefore(fakeElement, element);
            } 
            if(scrollY < top - offset && element.style.position != 'static') {   
                element.style.position = 'static';
                if (element.parentElement.contains(fakeElement)) {element.parentElement.removeChild(fakeElement);}
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);  
        window.addEventListener('resize', onResize); 
    }

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-sticky]');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            makeSticky(elements[i]);
    }
})()
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.paragraphe2Imaginary {
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  height: 4000px;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bababa;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: flex;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #505058;
  border-right: 1px solid #bababa;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  width: calc(75% - 10px);
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 2px dashed #bababa;
}
.sidebar-content {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>HTML de test</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/> 
        <script defer src="test.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <div class="topbar">LOGO</div>

            <div class="menu" data-sticky> 
                <a href="#">Item1</a>
                <a href="#">Item2</a>
                <a href="#">Item3</a>
                <a href="#">Item4</a>
                <a href="#">Item5</a>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <div class="main">
                    <h1>Je suis un titre</h1>
                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteriany variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefany variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic wordsany variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic wordsore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic wordsstic words etc.</p>    
                    <div class="paragraphe2Imaginary"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="sidebar-content" data-sticky data-offset="68" data-constraint=".sidebar">The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words he majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The snippet you posted seems to work fine.

Comment: First you must scroll down in order to have the "menu" and the "sidebar" to be "fixed". At the beginning, they are both "static" and it works.

Comment: Can you please explain what the purpose of this `fakeElement` is in all this?

Comment: Also, are you aware that this doesn't _need_ JavaScript any more these days? https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: @CBroe when the element becomes fixed, it goes to the top. In order to have a fluid movement, I add a fakeElement which has the same height than the menu. Comment it, you'll see an ugly offset when position goes to "fixed". And yes, I know, but as I said, I'm training myself.

Answer (score 1):

Problem found, just place line "fakeElement.style.display = "block";" at the end of the function after onScroll().

Comment: you can accept your own answer if you want